# How to fix error with xml2-config not found when installing PHP from sources?

Tags: php, compilation, php-5.3

When I try to install php 5.3 stable from source on Ubuntu (downloading compressed installation file from http://www.php.net/downloads.php) and I run `./configure` I get this error:

```
configure: error: xml2-config not found. Please check your libxml2 installation.
```

Comment: Related: [How to fix PHP installation when xml2-config is missing?](http://superuser.com/questions/740399/how-to-install-php5-3-instead-of-php5-5-in-linux)

Answer (score 477, accepted):

All you need to do instal install package libxml2-dev for example:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

On CentOS/RHEL:

```
sudo yum install libxml2-devel
```

Comment: I'm using centos 6.4, for me the package was called libxml2-devel

Comment: the same error is for installing php 5.5 in centos 7

Comment: for the error in centos 7 run: sudo yum install libxml2-devel

Comment: Does anyone know why the dev version is required over the standard `libxml2` package?

Comment: @JLewkovich I'd assume it's because the dev version contains the source code or something. As far as I can tell, if you compile something from source you must also have the source code for all it's dependencies.

Comment: This answer still applies to PHP7 for any PHP7 experimenters coming here

Comment: I install php7.10, and my libxml2-dev is installed, but the same error occured.

Comment: I get

libxml2-dev : Depends: libxml2 (= 2.9.3+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.5) but 2.9.4-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+2 is to be installed

Comment: This command allowed me to install R packages XML and rlist since they depend on libxml2 to work.

Answer (score 14):

For the latest versions it is needed to install libxml++2.6-dev like that:

```
apt-get install libxml++2.6-dev
```

Comment: This did the trick for me when trying to compile Zabbix 6.4 from source on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue when I used a DockerFile.
My Docker is based on the php:5.5-apache image.

I got that error when executing the command `RUN docker-php-ext-install soap`

I have solved it by adding the following command to my Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libxml2-dev
```

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu, Debian:

```
sudo apt install libxml2-dev
```

Centos:

```
sudo yum install libxml2-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

this solution it gonna be ok on Redhat 8.0

sudo yum install libxml2-devel

Answer (score 0):

OpenSuse

"**sudo zypper install libxml2-devel**"

It will install any other dependencies or required packages/libraries